# how to override material UI .Mui-selected on ListItemButton component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a list item button with a *selected* prop. That I would like to style in my createTheme() I'm trying to override the selected properties, but I can't get it to work.

```
//Navbar.js
<ListItemButton
   component={Link}
   to='/'
   selected={value === 0}
>

//primaryTheme.js
export default createTheme({
components: {
    MuiListItemButton: {
      root: {
        '&$selected': {
          color: '#5FBB7D',
          backgroundColor: '#F0F3F3',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MUI v5 they switched JSS to emotion so selecting with the dollar sign won't work anymore. You can target the component state using the className instead.

```
export default createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiListItemButton: {
      root: {
        '&.Mui-selected': {
          color: '#5FBB7D',
          backgroundColor: '#F0F3F3',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just make a overwrite in one behavior in your component, like a 'selected', you can use attribute 'sx' in your tag component. Looks like this:

```
<ListItemButton sx={{
        '&.Mui-selected': {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(220, 0, 50, 0.1)'
        }
      }} selected={0}> 
     <ListItemText primary={'label in item selected'} />
</ListItemButton>
```

i hope this helped you

Comment: this is good but I had to mark the other answer as I was looking for how to customize my `createTheme()`. Good to know though for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

styleoverrides is missing in previous sample:

```
MuiListItemButton: {
   styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        '&.Mui-selected': {
          color: '#5FBB7D',
          backgroundColor: '#F0F3F3',
        },
      },
    },
  },
```